# Podfile invalid syntax error

Tags: cocoapods

I am new to Cocoapods, the error states that I have a syntax error somewhere in my podfile but I can't find it, it must be a quote mark somewhere it is here,

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
>   .../user/Desktop/The Engineer's Workpad  (original)
>   ...                               ^
>   /Users/conoize/Desktop/The Engineer's Workpad  (original) /The Engineer's Workpad/Podfile:6: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
>   ...neer's Workpad  (original) /The Enginee...
>   ...                               ^
>   /Users/conoize/Desktop/The Engineer's Workpad  (original) /The Engineer's Workpad/Podfile:6: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   .../The Engineer's Workpad/TEW.xcodeproj'
>   ...

on podfile

```
platform :ios, '10.3'

target 'Side Menu' do

project '/Users/conoize/Desktop/The Engineer's Workpad  (original) /The Engineer's Workpad/TEW.xcodeproj'



  use_frameworks!

pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SwiftValidator'
pod 'paper-onboarding'


  # Pods for Side Menu


end
```

P.S. Side Menu was the initial name of the project.

Comment: Think about the single quotes in the project line

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like:

```
platform :ios, '10.3'
use_frameworks!

target 'Side Menu' do
  project 'TEW'

  pod 'SVProgressHUD'
  pod 'SwiftValidator'
  pod 'paper-onboarding'

end
```

You don't have to write the full path to your project file.

Comment: Great to hear that!